# From list to collapsible menu tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a collapsible/expandable menu tree from a list of ul and li nested elements.

Elements with class "section" are just folders, while elements with class "documents" are files.

I tried 4 or 5 differents methods from the internet, including pure CSS and jQuery, but I could make none of them work.

Right now I am trying with this script: https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Animated-Tree-View-Plugin-For-jQuery-Bootstrap-3-MultiNestedLists.html

Sadly I have no more luck with this one, as you can see on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkrch/zj1wuas6/3/)

Would you know where I did something wrong ? Maybe used the wrong selectors ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Btw, this part works on my computer, while it seems not to be working on JSFiddle:

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('li').each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0) {
            $this.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this part of code:

```
$this.html()
```

In that way you get the html instead of text, and that will be never empty. Use instead:

```
if(this.textContent.replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0) {
        jQuery(this).remove();
}
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg0hzmso/1/)

Instead, if you need to draw a folder/file it's enough to add to the first ul the class **multi-nested-list** with no js code as you can see in the following snippet.

Remember: after the first ul all the next ones need to be wrapped into a li. I translated only the first part of your html.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/olivsamuk/MultiNestedLists@master/style.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/olivsamuk/MultiNestedLists@master/MultiNestedList.js"></script>


<div class="table">
    <ul class="multi-nested-list">
        <li><a>Preface, revisions, and safety</a>
            <ul class="section">
                <li><a>Preface</a>
                    <ul class="section">
                        <li><a> </a>
                            <ul class="section">
                                <li><a> </a>
                                    <ul class="section">
                                        <li><a> </a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">Service documentation</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">About this documentation</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">About this product</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">Training</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">Trademarks</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="document">Feedback</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <ul class="section">
            <li><a>Revisions</a>
                <ul class="section">
                    <li><a>Service documentation</a>
                        <ul class="section">
                            <li><a> </a>
                                <ul class="section">
                                    <li><a> </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="document">Version 1.0</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="section">
                        <li><a>Revision history</a>
                            <ul class="section">
                                <li><a> </a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">Version 0.0</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="section">
            <li><a>Safety</a>
                <ul class="section">
                    <li><a> </a>
                        <ul class="section">
                            <li><a> </a>
                                <ul class="section">
                                    <li><a> </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="document">Introduction</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="document">About safety classifications</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="document">About additional information</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <ul class="section">
                <li><a>List of WARNING messages</a>
                    <ul class="section">
                        <li><a> </a>
                            <ul class="section">
                                <li><a> </a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About biohazardous material</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About chemical reaction producing toxic gas</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About class 2 laser radiation</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About class 2M laser radiation</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About class 3B laser radiation</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About consumables</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About disposal of instruments, control units or parts</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About electric ground</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About electrical hazards</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About electromagnetic interference</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About environmental conditions</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About fire and burns</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About moving parts</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About optical or ultra violet radiation</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About power interruption</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About reagents and working solutions</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About sharp objects</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About sharp points</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About spare parts</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About strong magnetic field</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About the control unit</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="section">
                <li><a>List of CAUTION messages</a>
                    <ul class="section">
                        <li><a> </a>
                            <ul class="section">
                                <li><a> </a>
                                <li><a class="document">About bridged lock sensors</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About heavy objects</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About hot surfaces</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About slippery surfaces due to condensation</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About software and data security</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About system cleaner</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <ul class="section">
                <li><a>List of NOTICE messages</a>
                    <ul class="section">
                        <li><a> </a>
                            <ul class="section">
                                <li><a> </a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About circuit breakers and fuses</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About electrostatic sensitive devices (ESD)</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About sprays</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About system cleaner replacement</a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About wireless interference</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="section">
                <li><a>About decontamination procedure prior to shipment</a>
                    <ul class="section">
                        <li><a> </a>
                            <ul class="section">
                                <li><a> </a></li>
                                <li><a class="document">About decontamination procedure prior to shipment</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you gaetano ! Would you know also why the tree is not collapsible ?

Comment: @user10879705 I'm sorry. Take a look now to my snippet.

Comment: Thanks again. I replaced <div class="table"> with <ul class="multi-nested-list" and replaced scripts with the first lines of your snippet, but it does the same. Did I do something wrong ? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkrch/k627r3f1/8/

Comment: @user10879705 No, your ul/li structure is wrong. Take a look to my snippet in order to solve your issue.

Comment: So I have removed the <ul> elements just below the ul with multi-nested-list so that no ul is nested directly inside an ul (see https://jsfiddle.net/vkrch/k627r3f1/14/) but it still does not work. What did I miss ?

Comment: Hi @gaetano, sorry to come back again but I would really be grateful if I could know what is still wrong in the structure. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @user10879705 I hope now it's all ok. Let me know